# Roots of polynomial with real coefficients appear in conjugate pairs.

Tags: complex-numbers

How to prove most simply that if a polyonmial $f$, has only real coefficients and $f(c)=0$, and $k$ is the complex conjugate of $c$, then $f(k)=0$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem

Comment: Did you try and conjugate $f(c)=0$? You get exactly $f(k)=0$, by using basic properties of the conjugation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at $\overline{f(c)}$ and use that conjugation is a homomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$. That is, $\overline{a+b} = \overline{a}+\overline{b}$ and $\overline{a\cdot b} = \overline{a} \cdot \overline{b}$.

Answer (score 4):

You use the fact that the coefficients of $f$ are real to show that
$$
f(\overline c)=\overline{f(c)}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I've long forgotten the details so maybe someone else can complete this.  I also don't see how folks have formatted the conjugate with the overhead bar so I will use ~ for conjugate.

When I took complex variable, the proof was along the lines of:

Suppose z1 is indeed a zero of f(z).
Assume ~z1 is **not** a zero of f(z).
Then 1/(fz) does not have a singularity at ~z1 i.e. 1/f(z1) is a permitted operation.

And that's where my memory fails me: Somehow, the professor (and the book) show that this leads to a contradiction.

Just a starter..

-- JS

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.